# Using arrays with Ctypes

Tags: ocaml

I have this quicksort function in C that I want to bind to OCaml using [Ctypes](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes).

The declaration is as follows:

```
void quicksort(int array[], int first, int last)
```

I don't know what type to put for array in the second parameter of foreign:

```
let cquicksort = foreign
    "quicksort" (??? @-> int @-> int @-> returning void)
;;
```

Comment: Did you try (ptr int @-> ...)

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Yes, I've tried that but quicksort wouldn't return with the correct result. It could be that something else was wrong with the code so I'm going to try again and keep you in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a void pointer like in [this](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/wiki/ctypes-tutorial) tutorial.

```
let cquicksort = foreign
    "quicksort" (ptr void @-> int @-> int @-> returning void)

let start = to_voidp (CArray.start (CArray.of_list int[1;2;3;4;3]));;

let () = 
    let carr = CArray.of_list int [1;2;4;5;3] in
        let start = to_voidp (CArray.start carr) in
            cquicksort start 0 4;
```

After the quicksort you can use `CArray.to_list` to get the sorted list.